# Getting negative score for model.docvecs.similarity_unseen_docs(document_1, document_2)

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, gensim

I'm trying to find out the similarity between 2 documents i.e 'document_1' and 'document_2'.
I'm using **Doc2Vec Gensim's *keyedvectors.py*** for finding similarity score.

```
score = model.docvecs.similarity_unseen_docs(trainedModel, document_1, document_2)
print(score)
```

Where score is negative.

Here document_1 and document_2 are result of *NLTK's word_tokenize()*

**What does Negative score mean when we try to find similarity between two "*tokenized*" documents?**

**P.S:** Trained the model on 10 documents(2 Pages each)=20 Pages MS
word documents.

Answer (score 1):

If it is using cosine-similarity, then the range is [-1, 1]. " It is thus a judgment of orientation and not magnitude: two vectors with the same orientation have a cosine similarity of 1, two vectors at 90° have a similarity of 0, and two vectors diametrically opposed have a similarity of -1, independent of their magnitude